# Cannot load message class for .... Are your messages built?

Tags: ros, robotino, messages, generate-messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen the other topics about the similar error (like here http://answers.ros.org/question/108976/rostopic-could-not-get-message-class-but-rosmsg-shows-msg/), but they don't seem to fit to my problem.

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Hydro.

I have a robotino_node which is publishing several things. They show up if I use rostopic list. i also can use rostopic type and rostopic info, here the robotino_node is listed as a publisher.
But if I use rostopic hz or rostopic echo the error form the topic line shows up, eg

```
Cannot load message class for [robotino_msgs/PowerReadings]. Are your messages built?
```

rosmsg show does also work, eg

```
[robotino_msgs/PowerReadings]
time stamp
float current
float voltage
```

Now interestingly if I try rostopic echo with "bumper", which is the only std_msg published by the robotino_node it shows one time

```
data: False
---
```

but that's it.

I suspect that my cmake file for the messages is wrong, but I am not sure; it looks like this

```
# CATKIN_MIGRATION: removed during catkin migration
# cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(robotino_msgs)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS geometry_msgs std_msgs message_generation roscpp)

include_directories(include
 ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_message_files(
FILES
AnalogReadings.msg
BHAReadings.msg
DigitalReadings.msg
EncoderReadings.msg
GrapplerReadings.msg
GripperState.msg
MotorReadings.msg
NorthStarReadings.msg
PowerReadings.msg
SetBHAPressures.msg
SetBHAPressures.msg
SetGrapplerAxes.msg
SetGrapplerAxis.msg)

add_service_files(
FILES
ResetOdometry.srv
SetEncoderPosition.srv
SetGripperState.srv)

#add_dependencies(robotino_msgs geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp) #or yes?
#target_link_libraries(robotino_msgs  ${catkin_LIBRARIES} ) # or yes
## Generate added messages and services with any dependencies listed here
generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES geometry_msgs std_msgs
)

# catkin_package parameters: http://ros.org/doc/groovy/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin-package
# TODO: fill in what other packages will need to use this package
catkin_package(
   DEPENDS roscpp geometry_msgs std_msgs
   CATKIN_DEPENDS # TODO
   INCLUDE_DIRS # TODO include
   LIBRARIES # TODO
)
```

My launch file looks like this

```
    <launch>
      <arg name="hostname" default="172.26.1.1" />
      
        <node name="robotino_node" pkg="robotino_node" type="robotino_node" output="screen">
            <param name="hostname" value="$(arg hostname)" />
            <param name="max_linear_vel" value="0.5" />
            <param name="min_linear_vel" value="0.05" />
            <param name="max_angular_vel" value="3.0" />
            <param name="min_angular_vel" value="0.1" />
    <!--        <param name="downsample_kinect" value="true" />
            <param name="leaf_size_kinect" value="0.04" />  entfernt da KinectNode nicht aktualisiert-->
            <remap from="robotino_joint_states" to="joint_states" />
            <!--remap from="image_raw" to="image"/-->
        </node>
    
    <!--
      <node name="robotino_odometry_node" pkg="robotino_node" type="robotino_odometry_node" output="screen">
        <param name="hostname" value="$(arg hostname)" />
      </node>
    -->
    <!--
      <node name="robotino_laserrangefinder_node" pkg="robotino_node" type="robotino_laserrangefinder_node" output="screen">
        <param name="hostname" value="$(arg hostname)" />
        <param name="laserRangeFinderNumber" value="0" />
      </node>
    -->
    
    <!--
      <node name="robotino_camera_node" pkg="robotino_node" type="robotino_camera_node" output="screen">
        <param name="hostname" value="$(arg hostname)" />
        <param name="cameraNumber" value="0" />
      </node>
    -->
        
        <node pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" name="robot_state_publisher" output="screen">
            <param name="publish_frequency" type="double" value="20.0" />
        </node>
        
    <!--
      <node name="robotino_mapping_node" pkg="robotino_node" type="robotino_mapping_node" output="screen">
        <param name="hostname" value="$(arg hostname)" />
      </node>

-->

    <!--node pkg="tf" type="static_transform_publisher" name="laser_link_broadcaster" args="0.12 0 0.025 0 0 0 base_link laser_link 50" /-->
    
    <param name="robot_description" textfile="$(find robotino_description)/urdf/robotino.urdf" />
</launch>
```

So even if just the std_msgs work, shouldn't at least the bumper published with a frequency of 20 hz?

I hope someone can helpt me out. Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/187071/cannot-load-message-class-for-....-are-your-messages-built?/) by [BenediktHeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/18056/benediktheck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2014-07-18

Post score: 13

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I know this is very late, but I just encountered the exact same problem. My problem originated from not having the .msg file added in my CMake file when I built. Here is how I resolved it:

First, ensure the file has been added to the CMakeLists.txt (yours already has)

Second, clean your build by running "catkin_make clean" in the root of your workspace.

Third, remake your project with "catkin_make"

Lastly, resource the devel/setup.bash in your workspace.

I know this is not a great answer, but I encountered the exact same problem where rosmsg could find my message, but rostopic could not, and these are the exact steps I took that resolved it.

---

Originally posted by [Carter12s](https://answers.ros.org/users/5109/carter12s/) with karma: 218 on 2014-08-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 18

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BenediktHeck](https://answers.ros.org/users/18056/benediktheck/) on 2014-08-20**:
Thank you. I believe that is the way I solved it, but I am not sure what exactly caused the error.
For completeness I should also mention, that I figured out why the bumper published only once. It and most other topics only publish something in the case of an event, not constantly with x Hz.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please Check your ROS_PACKAE_PATH. Make sure you run rostopic echo on your workspace executing terminal. Try following,

1. roscd or cd  ~/catkin_ws
2. source devel/setup.bash
3. rostopic echo  /topic

---

Originally posted by [Gayan Brahmanage](https://answers.ros.org/users/26769/gayan-brahmanage/) with karma: 929 on 2016-05-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 13

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ruoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/41370/ruoshi/) on 2019-05-07**:
It helps me to fix this problem. Thanks!!

**Comment by [Josh Liu](https://answers.ros.org/users/12601/josh-liu/) on 2019-05-17**:
It works for me. Thanks!

**Comment by [Kansai](https://answers.ros.org/users/54052/kansai/) on 2021-01-13**:
it did not help me. :(